# Can my public ip? If yes then how can change my public ip?

Tags: ip, public

Can I change my public ip?

If yes then how can change my public ip?

Comment: Can I change my public ip? If yes then how can change my public ip?

Comment: Your public up of what?

Comment: Your IP is provided by your ISP. Either run through a proxy server, or try turning your router on and off a few times

Comment: If you have a static IP, best is to contact your ISP to arrange that the IP be changed. If it's a dynamic IP, you can simply turn your router of for about 5 mins and turn it back on to get a new IP assigned to you.

Answer (score -1):

public IP address change dynamicly ,, Contact with your ISP for more details